# How do I check if a character is neither a letter nor a digit in Java?

Tags: java

So I'm writing some code in Java and I'm trying to find out if there is a way to write a line of code that checks if a character in a string is neither a letter nor a digit. I know that:

`Character.isDigit()` checks for a number

and

`Character.isLetter()` checks for a letter.

But I want to know if it is possible for java to check if neither of these are present in a single line of code. Like if the character is "/" or "*" or even "_" in the string.

I'm very new to Java so I'm not sure where to go at this point.

Answer (score 8):

[Java provides a method for that](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetterOrDigit(char)) - all you need to do is to negate its result:

```
if (!Character.isLetterOrDigit(ch)) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Can't believe that's been there since 1.0.2 and I never noticed it. (On the other hand, I don't think I've ever had a use for it, either.)

Comment: Awesome. Both this and the code from @RobertColumbia work perfectly. Thank you both for your help and quick response.

Answer (score 3):

You can combine both calls in a single expression that evaluates to a boolean.

```
if (!(Character.isDigit()) && !(Character.isLetter()) ) {
    //The character is neither a digit nor a letter.
    // Do whatever
}
```

By De Morgan's law, you can also express the same thing as follows:

```
if (!((Character.isDigit()) || (Character.isLetter()) )) {
   //The statement "The character is a digit or a letter" is false.    
   // Do whatever
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> code that checks if a character in a **string** is neither a letter nor a
>   digit.

From your question, I understand that you want to pass a `String` and check whether characters in that `String` are only letters and digits, or is there anything else.

You can use Regular Expressions for this purpose and check your `String` against `[^a-zA-Z0-9]`

**Output**

```
loremipsum -> false
loremipsum999 -> false
loremipsum_ -> true
loremipsum/ -> true
```

**Input**

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("loremipsum -> " + checkForCharAndDigits("loremipsum"));
        System.out.println("loremipsum999 -> " + checkForCharAndDigits("loremipsum999"));
        System.out.println("loremipsum_ -> " + checkForCharAndDigits("loremipsum_"));
        System.out.println("loremipsum/ -> " + checkForCharAndDigits("loremipsum/"));
    }

    public static boolean checkForCharAndDigits(String str) {
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile("[^a-zA-Z0-9]").matcher(str);
        if (m.find()) return true;
        else          return false;
    }
}
```